# UIWebView tel: phone link delegate not called on iPad (but it works on iPhone)

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiwebview

My UIWebView shows a web page which contains the URL tel:+123456789

```
<a href="tel:+123456789">Phone link</a>
```

When I click on this link on iPhone, my UIWebViewDelegate gets called correctly.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView
        shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
        navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

When I click on this link on iPad, my UIWebViewDelegate does not get called at all. Instead a UIActionSheet appears automagically with the options 'Add to Contacts', 'Copy' and 'Cancel'.

Is there a way to catch "tel:" HTML links from a UIWebView on a device that does not have phone capabilities e.g. an iPad.

This behaviour is the same for the simulator:

- iPhone simulator: delegate is called
- iPad simulator: delegate is not
  called

Comment: did you link the IBoutlet delegates on both storyboards?

Comment: The views are completely generated from code. I do not use storyboards

Comment: Seems it depends on device type (iPhone - can perform calls, iPad - can not). For full scope of view, need to test on iPod Touch.

Comment: I've been banging my head on this same issue for 2 days now. When an iPhone user taps this link, I want the call to go through.  When some other device does, I want to popup a message saying that they can't do it.  I'm almost at the point of declaring it can't be done.  I'm starting to consider doing a runtime string replace on the UIWebView HTML from tel: to a javascript alertbox.  I can't modify the HTML.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried a simple:

```
if ( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad )
{
     return YES; /* Device is iPad */
}
```

Comment: If his delegate is not called, where can he put this code?